# Automatically remove certificate from certificate store

Tags: windows-7, certificate, smartcard

Windows 7 certificate store's default behavior includes storing all public keys you use from smartcards. This is sometimes undesirable as if some machine needs to use a lot of smartcards, the "Please select a certificate" popup becomes increasingly crowded.

Is there a way to configure Windows such that the public key associated with a smartcard would be automatically removed from the certificate store once the smartcard is removed?

Or alternatively, a way to stop Windows from storing smartcard certificates in the store in the first place?

Comment: Are these certificates used for logon ?

Comment: No, just for Web application authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to automatically remove such certificates,
but you can clean them out by going to
Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Content tab -> Certificates.
Select the ones you want to get rid of, then click Remove.

Otherwise, you will need to write a utility that detects the smart-card insert event,
then lists and remembers all certificates, and finally deletes them from the
certificate store upon the smart-card removal event.

If you intend to go this way, besides the detailed documentation one can find
on the Microsoft website, here are some references that can give you
some understanding of the required programming :

[How to enumerate all certificates on a smart card](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121120932/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alejacma/archive/2010/12/15/how-to-enumerate-all-certificates-on-a-smart-card-powershell.aspx) (PowerShell, but can be adapted to C/C##)
[A Smart Card Framework for .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET)
[pcsc-sharp library](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731055647/https://code.google.com/p/pcsc-sharp/)

Comment: This sort of answers the question... I already knew, however, that I could develop a small utility for it. Just thought there could be a configuration/policy setting for it somewhere. In our company, employee custom developed code is always looked at with some suspicion.

Comment: Then they will also not let you modify Active Directory. Your own program can directly use a smart-card certificate, but normally a standard Web application will only consult the certificate store, so post-cleaning will be required. Perhaps something can be done for one particular type of Web applications, if you specify which is yours.

Comment: The Web application only consults the certificate store. I can modify Active Directory, just not justify deploying a custom made program without huge hassle. Altering group policy settings, as well as configuring Active Directory and all kinds of settings are standard procedures, whereas applications are white-listed.

Comment: After thinking, Active Directory won't help, except for serving as alternate store. AFAIK, you are only left with a program or a script for cleaning-up the store. Are scripts also looked at with suspicion?

Comment: I think a script would be allright. Do you think it would be possible to leverage the CryptoAPI on Powershell in order to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Or even a simple batch file using [certmgr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Once you know what to search for, google is your friend. An example powershell resource [is here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/11/19/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-tell-if-a-computer-has-a-smartcard-reader-attached.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command for removing all smartcard-certificates in your store:

`certutil -user -delstore my 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2`

Certificate of used smartcard will appear in certificate store, when you push in your smartcard to the reader.

For More details - check the 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2 on your favorite search engine.